# Sampler1D mapping blank with no errors

Tags: c++, opengl, textures, fragment-shader

I eventually hope to colorize an image based on 3 1d samplers. I wrote this quick program to test if I could map the red channel of a texture to itself, a so called linear mapping.

Right now the code is showing a blank screen, despite all of my error checking in the program, shader, and general execution. When I don't perform the mapping the texture renders as expected.

I am on a GeForce Ti 550, targeting Windows.

The method was largely inspired from: http://www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/Texturing/Tutorial%2014.html

**Make Texture and Sampler**

```
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glGenTextures(1,lut);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,lut[0]);
unsigned char* linear = new unsigned char[256];//should be a 1->1 mapping
for (int i = 0 ;i < 256;i++)
{
    linear[i] = i;
}
glTexImage1D(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0, GL_R8, 256, 0,GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, linear);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_BASE_LEVEL, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_1D, GL_TEXTURE_MAX_LEVEL, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D, 0);
delete linear;
glGenSamplers(1,sampler);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glSamplerParameteri(sampler[0], GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);   
glE();// no errors
```

**Make the program, also no errors**

```
const char *vsrc1 =
    "attribute vec2 vecPosIn;\n"
    "attribute vec4 texPosIn;\n"
    "varying vec4 texPosOut;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "gl_Position = vec4(vecPosIn, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
    "texPosOut = texPosIn;\n"
    "}\n";
GLint vsH = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
glShaderSource(vsH,1,&vsrc1,NULL);
glCompileShader(vsH);
shaderCheck(vsH);
glE();
const char *fsrc1 =
    "uniform sampler2D tex0;\n"
    "uniform sampler1D tex1;\n"
    "varying vec4 texPosOut;\n"
    "void main(void)\n"
    "{\n"
    //"    gl_FragColor = texture2D(tex0, texPosOut.st);\n" //ignores texture and does what I expect
    "    float red = texture2D(tex0, texPosOut.st).r;\n"
    "    gl_FragColor = texture1D(tex1, red);\n"
    "}\n";
GLint fsH = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
glShaderSource(fsH,1,&fsrc1,NULL);
glCompileShader(fsH);
shaderCheck(fsH);
glE();
//Bind
programHandle = glCreateProgram();
glBindAttribLocation(programHandle,0,"vecPosIn");
glBindAttribLocation(programHandle,1,"texPosIn");
glBindAttribLocation(programHandle,2,"texPosOut");
glE();
//Link
glAttachShader( programHandle, vsH );
glAttachShader( programHandle, fsH );
glLinkProgram( programHandle );
programCheck(programHandle);
glE();
//Set render() invariants
glUseProgram( programHandle );
GLuint idk = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "tex1");
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,lut[0]);
glUniform1i(idk,0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,0);
glUseProgram( 0 );
glE();
//Pack static data into a VAO
float vecData[] = {
    -1, 1,
    -1,-1,
    1, 1,
    -1,-1,
    1,-1,
    1, 1
};
float texData[] = { 
    0,1,
    0,0,
    1,1,
    0,0,
    1,0,
    1,1
};
vboHandles=(GLuint*)malloc(sizeof(int)*2);
glGenBuffers(2,vboHandles);
GLuint vecBuf=vboHandles[0];
GLuint texBuf=vboHandles[1];
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vecBuf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8*2 * sizeof(GLfloat), vecData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuf);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 8*2 * sizeof(GLfloat), texData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glE();
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vaoHandle );
glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);  // Vertex position
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);  // Vertex color
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vecBuf);
glVertexAttribPointer( 0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte *)NULL );
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texBuf);
glVertexAttribPointer( 1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte *)NULL ); //2 attribute per vertex
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glE();
```

**Render Function**

```
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);
glE();
//Bind
glUseProgram(programHandle);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,textures[frame]);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,lut[0]);
GLuint idk = glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "tex1");
glUniform1i(idk,0);
glBindSampler(0,sampler[0]);glE();
glE();
//Draw
glBindVertexArray(vaoHandle);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES,0,8);
glBindVertexArray(0);
glE();
//Unbind
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE1);
glBindSampler(0,0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_1D,0);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0);
glUseProgram(0);
glE();
//DumpFrame
glFlush();
glFinish();
glE();
```

Comment: Where are your `#version` directives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting

```
glUniform1i(idk,0);
```

so you tell the GL to use texture unit 0 to sample the "tex1" 1D texture, which is just invalid as you have a 2D texture bound there.

Comment: Thanks for the catch, I spent about 6 hours looking at this esoteric stuff.